# Connecting to MongoDB using NodeJS with Kerberos authentication from Windows fails with "The specified target is unknown or unreachable"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kerberos

Using the sample code at https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/5a1b61c9f2baf8f6f3cec4c34ce2db52272cd49d/docs/reference/content/tutorials/connect/authenticating.md, my code is as simple as the following but throws "**MongoServerSelectionError: InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable**".

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const fs = require("fs");

// KDC Server
const server = "linux.mydomain";
const principal = "myname@mydomain";
const urlEncodedPrincipal = encodeURIComponent(principal);
const dbName = "devDB"
const url = `mongodb://${urlEncodedPrincipal}@${server}/${dbName}?authMechanism=GSSAPI&authMechanismProperties=SERVICE_NAME:mongodb,CANONICALIZE_HOST_NAME:false,SERVICE_REALM:windows`;

const caChain = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/ca-cert.pem");

let mongoConnectOptions = {
    ssl: true,
    sslValidate: true,
    sslCA: caChain,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    replicaSet: "myReplica"
};

const client = new MongoClient(url, mongoConnectOptions);

// Let's write the actual connection code
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  client.close();
});
```

While the package.json is as the following:

```
{
  "name": "Try_Connect",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Connect.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "kerberos": "^1.1.3",
    "mongodb": "3.5.5"
  }
}
```

From my understanding, MongoDB server should also work as a proxy to send the authentication request to KDC server so no need to configure these on the client side. Not sure if the error is related to that or incorrect URL for a replicaSet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is a bug in the latest version of mongodb driver and/or kerberos library as downgrading solved the issue.

```
git diff .\package.json
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index d0172a7..0c893b4 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "fs": "0.0.1-security",
-    "kerberos": "^1.1.3",
-    "mongodb": "3.5.5"
+    "kerberos": "1.1.2",
+    "mongodb": "3.1.13"
   }
 }
```